# Losing information by editing?

Tags: discussion

These days, I feel really uneasy to see information being lost by editing.

For example:

- [This post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42569/%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB-biru-or-%E5%BB%BA%E7%89%A9-tatemono-as-a-translation-for-building-in-japanese/42572#42572) gained readability at the sacrifice of the information that the OP is familiar with romajis but not kanjis.
- I can't find the source now but recently someone got his greetings deleted from his post.

Is this kind of editing allowed or even recommended?

Although it may not affect the topic of a question, it may affect the way in which we make an answer.
I think it should not be done, or be done after the question is ended.

---

**Edit**: I tried to say "Hi, I'm new to meta" and was rejected by the system. So I understood that greetings are not wanted here. I still want to discuss the first example.

Comment: あいさつ文に関しては、「Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.」（http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/behavior）というルールが‌​あるために削除されるようです。「ローマ字→仮名・漢字」に関しては、romanization systems がたくさんある （http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/810/9831）、検索でヒットしない（http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1022/9831）などの問題があるそうです。